# howto do A* Navigation on a QuadTree

Tags: navigation, path-finding, a-star, quadtree

I wanna do navigation/A* on a QuadTree.

I already implemented a QuadTree, or at least what I think is a QuadTree. Meanwhile I have seen some where also the inner nodes contain elements. With mine the inner nodes only link to their children and the elements are stored in collections in leaf nodes.
While each node links to its parent there are (currently) no links to the neighbors, neither siblings nor nodes of other branches. Elements are regions and not just points.

I have also seen A* quite some time on grids and even a demo on QuadTree, but this was without details.

I guess the main question is how do I quickly get to my neighbors?

I am not sure if I should keep the leafs linked to each other. But this would be a hell of a job as the tree is dynamic as the elements update their position. It would also need need some king of dynamic collection for the links as depending on the node size a big leaf can have a lot of small leafs on one direction (e.g. East). The effort to update this seems quite huge, even currently don't know how I would do it.

Thx n rgds

Answer (score 0):

A* is an algorithm for finding the shortest path from a start-node to a finish-node.  This doesn't really make much sense in trees, since the shortest path is always to go up from the start to the [least-common-ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor), then down to the finish.

If for some reason you weren't able to locate the finish within the tree, you'd have to treat the tree as a normal graph and do a breadth-first search *(or A*, if you had some sort of heuristic)*

> I guess the main question is how do I quickly get to my neighbors?

Store a pointer to each node's parent within the tree.  Then a node's siblings can be viewed by viewing all its parent's children.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it is for sure not optimal. A* is done on graph datastructures. Where 'graph' means a node can be accessed very fast - preferable via a direct pointer/reference.

The normal way to get neighbors via quadtree is [explained on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) - so, check recursivly if the subentry is within the query bounds. It is also [already implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

If you additionally need A* you could go the otherway around: use a normal graph, do A* on it and implement a nearest neighbor search [directly on the graph](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/storage/Location2IDQuadtree.java).